# Camel complex type to string typeconverter error

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using Camel with Spring Boot. During a service route implementation which is basically logging message body, I have seen an error which is like below.

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [com.example.Book] to type [java.lang.String]
```

My Route is :

```
from(REST_ENDPOINT_URI)
    .log("${headers}")
    .log("${body}")
```

and I get error in log body line.

My question is that expected behaviour? Why isn't Camel just calling the `toString` method of the `Book` object. And also if this is the expected behaviour then I need a string converter for every new complex type ?

Comment: did you try .log("${body.toString}") ? Assuming a toString() is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a runnable example that reproduces the issue? This is definitely a scenario that Camel handles by invoking `toString`.

For instance, you can test it with:

```
@Component
public class DemoRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {


  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("timer:sender?delay=5s&period=3s")
        .setBody(constant(new Book("Lord of the Rings", "J.R.R. Tolkien")))
        .log("${body}!");
  }

  public static class Book {
    private final String title;
    private final String author;

    public Book(String title, String author) {
      this.title = title;
      this.author = author;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Book{" +
          "title='" + title + '\'' +
          ", author='" + author + '\'' +
          '}';
    }
  }
}
```

This results in the following output:

> 2016-08-30 11:57:49.802  INFO 8778 --- [ timer://sender] route1 : Book{title='Lord of the Rings', author='J.R.R. Tolkien'}!
>
> 2016-08-30 11:57:52.792  INFO 8778 --- [ timer://sender] route1 : Book{title='Lord of the Rings', author='J.R.R. Tolkien'}!
>
> 2016-08-30 11:57:55.795  INFO 8778 --- [ timer://sender] route1 : Book{title='Lord of the Rings', author='J.R.R. Tolkien'}!